# sessionAsSigner returning "undefined"

Tags: xpages

I'm having a problem with the **sessionAsSigner** object: it returns "undefined" if one of the custom controls used on an XPage is signed by another user than the XPage. This is annoying (at the least) if you're working with multiple users on the same application.

Has anyone else experienced this? Or can anyone tell me if this is "by design"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also experienced this.

My guess is that it is 'as designed' as the renderer would have no sure way to know who the signer actually is when presented with two or more signing signatures.

Best practice is to always sign the entire application before testing or pushing to production with a signing ID.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen HTTP 500 errors with two signers. It is one of the reasons in my mind when looking at source control and working on a local server.

Equally I think there are problems with two Java classes that use sessionAsSigner. I've found that when I had that, things were fine for a while, but after about half an hour the server crashed. I couldn't see anything in the NSD logs to certainly point to that, but was able to reproduce it. And when I signed the database, I had no problems.

Comment: Thanks Paul for adding this. I've seen the 500 error also numerous times while working in an application with 2 signers. This might explain why that's happening.